# Do arrow functions have a higher priority than normal functions?

Tags: javascript

Both of the following snippets print "arrow". I would like to know why. Do arrow functions have a sort of higher priority than the normal functions if they both have the same name?

```
function increment(){
    alert("normal")
}


var increment = () => {
    alert("arrow")
}

increment(); //prints arrow
```

```
var increment = () => {
    alert("arrow")
}


function increment(){
    alert("normal")
}


increment(); //prints arrow
```

Comment: Try the same thing but using let or const instead. variables defined using var are available in the whole scope regardless of the order, that's why I think it can override your function.

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with arrow functions. Rather, *regular* functions (and `var` declarations) are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting); regardless of where you write them, they are moved to the top of their scope. Effectively, both code samples are completely identical, and they look like this:

```
var increment; // hoisted

function increment() { // hoisted
    alert("normal")
}

increment = () => { // the assignment itself is unaffected
    alert("arrow")
}

increment(); //prints arrow
```

The assignment portion of `var increment = ...` occur *after* the hoisted function and `var` declaration, in both cases.  Regardless of where you actually wrote the `function increment() { }` declaration, it is hoisted above the line performing assignment to the `increment` variable.

This is why the following code still works, despite the function apparently being defined *after* it is used:

```
increment(); //prints normal

function increment(){
    console.log("normal")
}
```

If you want to compare like with like, you need to compare `var increment = () => { ... }` with `var increment = function () { ... }`, that is, two assignments. The results look like this:

```
var increment = () => { console.log('arrow'); }
var increment = function () { console.log('normal'); }

increment(); # normal
```

vs

```
var increment = function () { console.log('normal'); }
var increment = () => { console.log('arrow'); }

increment(); # arrow
```

In both cases there is a single hoisted `var increment;` declaration, and then the assignments occur in the order in which they're written, meaning the last assignment wins.

---

As an aside, this is one of the chief reasons to prefer `let x = () => { }` over "old" style function declarations. `let` is not hoisted, so the function exists from the point in time you would naturally expect it to, instead of jumping to the top of your scope.